# Keyword search and rank result

Tags: php, mysql

Let say I have 5 documents as rows and 2 columns 'document' and 'description' in my mySQL table.

- Document 1: John and Nancy are best friends.
- Document 2: John, Casey, David, Nancy are best friends.
- Document 3: Nancy and Casey are best friends.
- Document 4: David is in relationship with Casey. David and Casey are madly in love.
- Document 5: David and John are siblings.

So if the search query is "David Casey", how to calculate the query based on terms frequency in all the 5 documents and rank the result based on the frequency.

In this case, the result should be like this:

- Document 4 (because of there are 2 'David' and 2 'Casey')
- Document 2 (1 'David' and 1 'Casey')
- Document 3 (1 'Casey')
- Document 5 (1 'David')

I've read many tf-idf articles but none of them can help me. I don't have the idea on how to write the codes.

This is my current code:

> $searchCondition = "description LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR description LIKE '%", $searchTerms) . "%'";
>
> $query = "SELECT description FROM table1 WHERE $searchCondition ORDER BY description ASC";
>
> $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> ...

Comment: Welcome to SO! As an aside, your code contains [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) vulnerabilities that you should fix.

Comment: Have you looked into MySQL's Full-Text search functions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Already, but I still don't have the idea. :/

Comment: Should I use array or something?

Comment: No you have to use other mysql commands, see here: http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/ It's a good tutorial!

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but I must use the tf-idf ranking function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for sure:

```
$searchCondition = "description LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR description LIKE '%", $searchTerms) . "%'";
$orderCondition = array();
foreach ($searchTerms as $word) {
    $orderCondition[] = "(length(description)-length(replace(description,\"".$word."\",\"\")))/length(\"".$word."\")";
}
$orderConditionString = "(".implode(" + ", $orderCondition).")";

$query = "SELECT description FROM table1 WHERE $searchCondition ORDER BY $orderConditionString DESC";
```

The items from the database are sorted then in descending. So the most relevant gets the first place.

note: This works fine only when the number of key-words is small. Because of checking 3 times for length for each keyword. So the responsetime on bigger tables and more keywords wight be a bit different ;)

Comment: Thanks @AndVla, the coding is working! However, the result were not ranked as what I have mention in the first post. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You want to get the rank of each row from database in your result-query?

Comment: Yes, as I implemented your codes into my php, the result is 2,4,5,3. The result should be 4,2,3,5 according to my query: "David Casey". I wonder how to work on this.

Comment: That should be your query then:
 $query = "SELECT description, $orderConditionString as rank FROM book WHERE $searchCondition ORDER BY rank DESC";

Comment: There's an extra column to see what rank it gets. I've created a table 'book' in my database with the data you've provide in your example. Then just executed my query and works fine for "David Casey": 4, 2, 3, 5

Comment: Thanks @AndVla! It worked! Is this method called "boolean search"?

Comment: Don't know what the mathod is called like. I don't learn the names of methods, just learn to use them and think further than the method allows :) Once more: It works great, but I haven't tested it out with more keywords on a huge table. There's may be a better method therefor...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, however, I have added more documents and some of the results are not ranked properly. :| Would you mind if we have a chat somewhere else to avoid long discussion at here?

Comment: For example I have 30 documents. It won't rank properly. @AndVla

Comment: How about this one @AndVla?

tf-idf(WORD) = occurrences(WORD,DOCUMENT) / number-of-words(DOCUMENT) * log10 ( documents(ALL) / ( 1 + documents(WORD, ALL) ) )