# Ranking document based on searched terms

Tags: php, sql

How can I implement this

> tf-idf(WORD) = occurrences(WORD,DOCUMENT) / number-of-words(DOCUMENT) * log10 ( documents(ALL) / ( 1 + documents(WORD, ALL) ) )

into my PHP codings for ranking search results?

Can refer here for the current codings:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/8574651/1107551

Comment: @chris That edit isn't helpful to **anyone**.  Downvote or comment or flag (or all three).  No need to add a useless (sarcastic) tag.  This was briefly the only question on the site with that tag.

Comment: Indeed. That tag used to be pretty common, but we *finally* got rid of it. Please don't start it again, @chris.

Comment: What had happened in here @jadarnel and @michael?

Comment: Someone added a tag to your question that is frowned upon.  It's all good now.

Answer (score 1):

I only understand part of what you are asking for, but I think I can help you with the `occurrences(WORD,DOCUMENT) / number-of-words(DOCUMENT)` part:

```
<?php
function rank($word, $document)
{
    // Swap newlines for spaces, you'll see why
    $document = str_replace("\n",' ',$document);
    // Remove special characters except '-' from the string
    for($i = 0; $i <= 127; $i++)
    {
        // Space is allowed, Hyphen is a legitimate part of some words. Also allow range for 0-9, A-Z, and a-z
        // Extended ASCII (128 - 255) is purposfully excluded from this since it isn't often used
        if($i != 32 && $i != 45 && !($i >= 48 && $i <=57) && !($i >= 65 && $i <= 90) && !($i >= 97 && $i <= 122))
            $document = str_replace(chr($i),'',$document);
    }
    // Split the document on spaces. This gives us individual words
    $tmpDoc = explode(' ',trim($document));
    // Get the number of elements with $word in them
    $occur = count(array_keys($tmpDoc,$word));
    // Get the total number of elements
    $numWords = count($tmpDoc);

    return $occur / $numWords;
}
?>
```

I'm sure there are more efficient ways to do this, but there are surely also much worse ways.

*Note: I did not test the PHP code*